# Reduce font size of incoming mail in Outlook 2007

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, fonts

Is there a way to reduce the font size of an incoming HTML email in Outlook 2007 if it's above a certain size? I find huge fonts in emails really annoying.

I suspect I may need to write a script?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to look into is how the original message from the recipient to see how its being formatted. It's most likely going to be in HTML format for the pretty colors, font sizes, etc.

There's not a whole lot that can be done unless you ask them to have their IT personnel (if they have one at work) or to create the email as plain text.